# Get all element from within an iFrame

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How to get all element within an iFrame? I am using some javascript code here but I don't know what I do next and how to get all element inside in iframe:

```
<iframe id="uploads" src="https://jsfiddle.net/mekwall/up4nu/"></iframe>

var iframe = document.getElementById('uploads');
var innerDoc = iframe.contentDocument;
```

I'm using `contentDocument` it's gives only `<html><body></body></html>`

Comment: You cannot read contents of another domain with Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Hello this is your code executed in jsfiddle.
Its showing error in console.

see screenshot: http://prntscr.com/c54jts

The reason for that error is mentioned here:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Errors/Property_access_denied

For more details: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy

Summery: You can't access the content of iframe if its from different domain.